# Thymeleaf and SpringBoot - Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for prope

Tags: spring-boot, datepicker, thymeleaf

I am building a web application using Thymeleaf and SpringBoot, I am new to both the technologies.

In my html file, there is a Date field as follows:

```
<input type="date" th:field="*{issueDate}" />
```

My model class has a field corresponding to issueDate as follows:

```
@NotNull(message = "Cannot be empty")
private Date issueDate;
```

When I input a date from the UI, I see the following exception in the browser:

```
    Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property issueDate;
```

From my experience, I understand that the UI reads the property as a String, but the model expects a type Date due to which the error occurs. So I need to convert the String to a Date. However where should this be done? Since the error occurs even before the setter method in the model is invoked.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your controller and more of your html file, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true));
}
```

WHERE "MM/dd/yyyy" is the date format you're using.

Comment: Thanks for responding, that worked, so an exception is no longer thrown. However, date does not seem to be parsed correctly, the wrong date gets stored in the DB. I will check that out. The other thing I wanted to know was, when does this initBinder method get invoked? Does it get invoked before the setter methods in the model?

Comment: Yes, it's all part of the process.  It's called automatically by spring when populating the model (before setters are called).  As for parsing the date, you have to change the date to format I supplied ("MM/dd/yyyy") to the date format you are using, according to this specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks again, that was helpful. I also figured out the date issue, don't know why but date format is required as yyyy-MM-dd, so when I set this date format in the initBinder, it worked fine. I am using html date type as input in the form, so when a user inputs a date it is input as dd-MM-yyyy. So not sure why yyyy-MM-dd worked!