# Spring: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-time

I have a Spring Boot application running Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. One of its entities is the `Purchase` entity, containing the field `date` which is of `LocalDateTime` type:

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {

    // Other fields

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Please note that this field is already annotated with `@DateTimeFormat` specifying the `pattern` of `dd-MM-yyyy`, which happens to be the same one defined in my `form.html`:

```
<form id="purchaseForm" th:action="@{/purchases/(form)}"
            th:object="${purchase}" action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- Purchase's date -->
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Date</label>
        <input class="col-sm-10" type="text" id="date" th:field="*{date}" 
            th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('date')} ? 'field-error'"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

That given date is formatted in the form like `14-12-2017`. 
This form is then processed by the `PurchaseController` after submission:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/purchases")
public class PurchaseController {

    @PostMapping(params = "form")
    public ModelAndView create(@Valid Purchase purchase, BindingResult result,
            RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

After submission, I get the following error:

```
Field error in object 'purchase' on field 'date': rejected value [12-12-2017]; 
codes [typeMismatch.purchase.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDateTime,typeMismatch];
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [purchase.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]];
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'date';
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '12-12-2017'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [12-12-2017]]
```

Which I don't quite understand the reason, since the rejected value `'12-12-2017'` follows the pattern I've defined within the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation. Moreover, the javadoc of `@DateTimeFormat` tells us that it works with the `java.time` new types.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009394/thymeleaf-and-springboot-failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-s) worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you @mavefreak, I will give it a shot and will update it here.